# Remote sync without rsync

Tags: linux, backup, sync, rsync, sftp

My setup is as follows:

- Two Linux machines running Debian 9
- A "storage box" on the internet rented from a cloud hosting company. This box can only be accessed via the SFTP, Samba and WebDAV protocols for transferring data. **I have no means of installing any software on it**, since it is not a server, only a "dumb" storage device. I do not have any SSH access either.

Now, here's what I would like to do:

1. Synchronize a directory across my two Debian machines.
2. Do this incrementally, so I don't have to upload and download the entire directory structure every time.

What I've tried so far:

- **rsync**: Basically `rsync -avz /path/to/dir/local/machine USER@remote_address.com`.
  The problem: The remote storage box does not have `rsync` installed to act as a server. Therefore, the entire directory has to be parsed (and therefore transferred) every time, which is slow.
- **WebDAV mount**: Mounted remote directory locally using `fusedav` and did an `rsync` locally. This took too long since modify times are not preserved when uploading via `fusedav` so `rsync` has to checksum each file.
- **Duplicity**: Incremental backups work fine over SFTP. There is, however, no possibility to do an incremental restore over existing files. It downloads the entire directory each time.
- **Borg Backup**: Same issue as with duplicity, no incremental restores (that I found).

Is there any backup solution that offers incremental restore and works over SFTP? Or can I make rsync work quickly (I thought of some kind of cache, though that doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: What about [`rsync -h -v -r -P -t source target`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67539/how-to-rsync-only-new-files) or consider testing with Rsync `--ignore-existing` parameter as that post suggests. Or look for an alternative non-Rsync solution such as [`find . -newer xmrkite.date /path/to/backup-dir -exec scp '{}' user@host:'{}' \; && touch xmrkite.date`](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/sftp-client-that-can-sync-via-command-line-4175424470/).... Quick research and ideas for you!!